# c++ make failing on forward declaration - running in docker

Tags: c++, docker, cmake

I'm compiling the following library using docker:

https://github.com/hot-stuff/libhotstuff

using the following script:

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk update
RUN apk add --no-cache git gcc g++ make cmake libuv-dev openssl-dev gmp-dev libsodium-dev autoconf
RUN git clone https://github.com/hot-stuff/libhotstuff.git && cd libhotstuff/ && git submodule update --init --recursive
RUN cd libhotstuff && cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_SHARED=ON -DHOTSTUFF_PROTO_LOG=ON && make
```

Resulting in the following exception:

```
In file included from /libhotstuff/include/hotstuff/util.h:21,
                 from /libhotstuff/src/util.cpp:17:
/libhotstuff/salticidae/include/salticidae/util.h:244:20: error: field 't0' has incomplete type 'salticidae::timeval'
  244 |     struct timeval t0;
      |                    ^~
/libhotstuff/salticidae/include/salticidae/util.h:71:30: note: forward declaration of 'struct salticidae::timeval'
   71 | void sec2tv(double t, struct timeval &tv);
      |                              ^~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/hotstuff.dir/build.make:82: CMakeFiles/hotstuff.dir/src/util.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:289: CMakeFiles/hotstuff.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:149: all] Error 2
```

Meanwhile I'm able to run it nicely on my own machine and others too.
(Manually outside of docker)

Comment: It's good that you've posted exact errors (many fail to do that) but unfortunately you haven't posted any code. It's tricky to diagnose code errors without seeing the code. Although in this case the basic error seems clear enough, you haven't included the correct headers in `util.h`.

Comment: There is no code, I'm basically just trying to compile a library in a dockerfile and it fails, meanwhile when I do it outside of the docker context it works fine for me. The docker script I've included above.

Comment: According to Posix standard, the `timeval` struct is defined in the header file `<sys/time.h>` so maybe you failed to include that.

Comment: *There is no code* The library is the code you're trying to compile.

Comment: Correction: There is no code for me to add to the issue. Since compiling the library works fine in a bunch of circumstances, I believe the error is not in the code I'm trying to compile but in the docker setup.

Comment: So one possibility is that your docker environment includes a bad or wrong version of the file `<sys/time.h>`, another possibility is that your library is bugged. Clearly the first thing you should do is look at the code (there is some code) and try and establish if sys/time.h is being included or not.

Comment: @user2524707 That's not a foregone conclusion, working code can have bugs which only show in a certain situation.

Comment: @user2524707 Perhaps the most likely scenario is that the code involved is drawing some wrong conclusion about your platform based on some environmental factor or other. So again the only way to determine this is to look at the code.

Comment: https://github.com/Determinant/salticidae/blob/master/include/salticidae/util.h

That is the util.h, but like I said, I've been using this library for ages, running it super fine without a problem and based on the issues reported to the library, numerous people have too. Just in the docker env it's failing.

Comment: @user2524707: Well, you have faced with a problem with the library. If you don't know internals of that library and don't want to know them, then report the problem to the library's developers, into appropriate bugtracker. There is nothing wrong in that approach. We (Stack Overflow) could **help** you in fixing the problem, but only if you decide to **fix it by yourself**. In that case we expect you to have more knowledge about the library and expect you to show more debugging efforts.

Comment: @user2524707 Well I would be looking at `#include "salticidae/config.h"`, presumably that file is generated. Has it been generated correctly for your docker environment, or has it been generated for some different environment and then copied to your docker environment? That's the kind of issue you should be investigating.

Comment: `FROM alpine:latest` Most probably you are compiling your library under glibc, whereas `alpine` uses `musl` and they differ. You should notify developers, that to use `timeval` they should include `#include <sys/time.h>`. The source code is broken, that's why it does not work.

Comment: @KamilCuk oh, that might really be the case. If that is the case, the only way to fix that is within the library then, right?

Comment: I do not understand "within the library". You can write a patch, and store it outside the library source code.

Comment: @KamilCuk yeah that's what I meant with "within the library". (adjusting the code of the library and then either making a PR to them or, somehow, integrating this patch into the docker setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> c++ make failing on forward declaration - running in docker

The linked source file [util.h](https://github.com/Determinant/salticidae/blob/master/include/salticidae/util.h) does not `#include <sys/time.h>` which is needed for `struct timeval`. Indeed, the identifier has incomplete type.

Technically C source includes would be better to incalude inside `extern "C"`, so do [at line 28](https://github.com/Determinant/salticidae/blob/master/include/salticidae/util.h#L28):

```
#ifdef __cplusplus     // POSIX headers should be inside extern "C"
extern "C" {           // but there are no actual platforms 
#endif                 // where this is needed, so anyway...
#include <getopt.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/time.h>  // add this for timeval
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

With good luck it should work.

> Meanwhile I'm able to run it nicely on my own machine and others too.

Most probably you are being able to run it with `glibc`, whereas `alpine` uses `musl` as the C standard library implementation. You might want to save yourself the work of patching the library, as there may be further incompatibilities that may need to be fixed, and before the library gets patched upstream to work with `musl`, I would advise to just use a compatible docker image that uses `glibc`.

Comment: Thanks, is there an alternative to alpine you'd indicate?

Comment: ubuntu debian centos . People usually use the same distribution they are using.